# iText Paragraph overflow handling

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How can i handle really long dynamic text for a paragraph which is in a fixed rectangle in iText document ?

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
Font paragraphFont=new Font(baseFont,4.5f);
ct.setSimpleColumn(9, 70, 70, 95);
Paragraph paragraph=new Paragraph("REALLLLLLLLLLY LONGGGGGGGGGG text",paragraphFont);
ct.addElement(paragraph);
ct.go();
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Could you add to your question more details about the problem and how you want things to work (wrapping, clipping, ... etc). Maybe you could add an image of how you want such text to appear?

Comment: The text will wrap to fit the rectangle you defined. Text that doesn't fit won't be rendered. It's stored in the column so that you can add it at another position. Did you read the [iText FAQ](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text)?

Answer (score 1):

I have copy/pasted your code snippet in an example which I named [SimpleColumn](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples/objects-columns#1586-simplecolumn.java):

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 120);
    Document document = new Document(rect);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont();
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
    Font paragraphFont=new Font(baseFont,4.5f);
    ct.setSimpleColumn(9, 70, 70, 95);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("REALLLLLLLLLLY LONGGGGGGGGGG text",paragraphFont);
    ct.addElement(paragraph);
    ct.go();
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

This results in the file [simple_column.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/columntext/cmp_simple_column.pdf):

[image]

As you can see, the text is displayed correctly inside a rectangle of which the lower-left corner has the coordinates `x = 9; y = 70` and the upper-right corner has the coordinates `x = 70, y = 95`. The text didn't fit the width of this rectangle, so it was wrapped (split at the white space character and distributed over two lines).

This is how long paragraphs are handled when you want to render them in a fixed rectangle. If the paragraph doesn't fit the rectangle, the remainder of the paragraph is stored in the `ColumnText` object. You can define a new simple column (using different coordinates) to render the rest of the paragraph.